# BP Profile search results won't link to user's profile page

Tags: buddypress, s2member

I have installed the bp profile search along with s2member and want to perform profile searches amongst the different levels of membership, however, when the search results display and I click on one of the search results, their profile page will not display.  It always puts "author/" before the members profile name in the url.  How can I remove the "author/" from the url?

Answer (score -1):

I used a plugin called "edit author slug"  Changed the /author/ to /members/.

Comment: You should add at least a link to the plugin. A good explanation would be even better.